# how to purge azure acr failed tasks?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

When I issue command:
`az acr task list-runs --registry <regname> --output table`

I get a long list of some failed and successful tasks. I want to purge the failed ones so it's easier to read the table. How can I do this? I found articles [Automatically purge images from an Azure container registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auto-purge) that show how to set up a task to purge old container images, but not tasks. Also looking at the documentation on, I can't seem to delete a specific task based on tag label, [az acr task delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr/task?view=azure-cli-latest#az_acr_task_delete). Is this even do-able? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the parameter `--run-status` to filter the failed task:

```
az acr task list-runs --registry <regname> --run-status Succeeded --output table
```

And you only can delete the task by the name, the tag label does not be supported.

Comment: ok thanks for clarification. out of curiosity, is there a reason why we can't purge the tasks by tag label?

Comment: @SpencerTrinh The simplest explanation is Azure CLI does not make it supported. You can feedback, but currently, it does not support it. And if it solves your problem please accept it.